# Patching and unpatching object method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class with multiple methods. One of these methods use a seed and pseudorandom numbers (using RandomState, to allow seeds to be independent). Let's call it method GEN_RND().

The problem is when trying to create a unittest for a method that uses GEN_RND (let's call it MY_METHOD()).
I'd like to *temporarily* mock GEN_RND, just for this one test, and then "unpatch" it, for the rest of the tests.
Any idea how to do that?

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def mock_GEN_RND(x, y):
    return 3

class TestMyObj(unittest.TestCase):
    obj_instance = MyObj()

    @patch.object(MyObj, 'GEN_RND', mock_GEN_RND)
    def test_MY_METHOD(self):
        x = obj_instance.MY_METHOD(0.3) 
        self.assertEqual(x, 3)  # test uses mock and should pass
    
    # How to "un-patch" from here to avoid inadvertently using mock_GEN_RND 
    # in subsequent tests?
```

Comment: Patches applied as decorator or context manager are temporary.

Comment: To reiterate, and make sure I understand correctly: the scope of this patch is actually only within test_MY_METHOD() ?

Comment: Exactly, only within the decorated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted answer by Klaus D.
The mock exists only within the scope of the decorated method.